# OpenAM, OpenDJ, OpenIDM Production Requirement

Tags: openam, opendj, openidm, forgerock

My client want to use OpenAM OpenIDM and OpenDJ for the product development. Before that client want to know what will be the production sizing for this forgerock.
Our plan is to have the 1 million user and 100K concurrent users are there then how much size it will take to on production. I have gone through the documentation of forgerock but didn’t find much information from it.

Answer (score 0):

Deepak,

I am from ForgeRock and we would be very happy to help. As everyone's situation is different, we would like to discuss your requirements before providing sizing details to make sure we are not over / underestimating. ie. We want to get it right. :-)

There are a couple of options for getting in touch with your nearest tech resources.

1. Ping your request to this email address info@forgerock.com. If you could include the detail you have in this question, as well as your country and city, it will help the right person pick up your question and get in touch.
2. Here is a URL to our offices. I suggest calling your closes office for assistance. https://www.forgerock.com/contact/
3. If you can tell me your country / city, I can put you in touch with your nearest engineer.

Matt.